# Javascript capturing ctrl+alt+c

Tags: javascript, jquery, key-bindings, hotkeys

In my web app I want to use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> as hotkey.

I read bunch of Stack Overflow articles and came up with below solution

```
$(document).keydown(function(e){
   if(e.ctrlKey && e.altKey && e.which == 99){
     e.preventDefault();
     window.prompt("Copy to clipboard: Ctrl+C, Enter", text);
   }
});
```

This is not working in chrome. I tried debugging.

What I noticed is as soon as I press ctrl key it goes into function and as if condition fails it is coming out.

How can I get this to work.

Comment: perhaps you'd be interested in http://robertwhurst.github.io/KeyboardJS/

Comment: `e.which` for `c` is `67`, not `99`. Am i miss-understanding your intentions? http://jsfiddle.net/M2jc2/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/M2jc2/ fiddle for previous comment (too late to edit)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two mistakes in you code

```
1st : keycode of c is 67
2nd : text variable is undefined.
```

So the final code would be

```
$(document).keydown(function(e){
   if(e.ctrlKey && e.altKey &&  e.which == 67){
      e.preventDefault();
       prompt("Copy to clipboard: Ctrl+C, Enter","text");
   }
  });
```

you can check the fiddle  [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ED5S7/)

Answer (score 3):

Use the event `keypress` instead. [Example on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BtTr4/).

```
$(document).keypress(function(e)
{
    if (e.which == 8354) // ctrl+alt+c
    {
       e.preventDefault();
       console.log("success");
    }
    else
    {
        console.log("fail");
    }
    console.log(e);
});
```

Comment: weird... on your fiddle, i can get "fail" to show up, but not success. When i press ctrl+alt+c i get nothing, no fail, no success. doesn't make sense. testing in chrome. Maybe that key-combination is being used by chrome?

Comment: Which browser/version? I tested on IE 11, Firefox latest, Chrome 32, http://i.imgur.com/9zIrZe6.png

Comment: Chrome Version 31.0.1650.63 m ctrl+anything doesnt trigger the event. It does using keydown though. http://jsfiddle.net/M2jc2/

Comment: even without it at all it isn't triggering while ctrl is pressed. http://jsfiddle.net/BtTr4/2/