# How to delete all pressed and cached key codes from JavaScript when pressing ctrl + alt + delete

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyboard, jquery-events

Our app has some functionality that reacts on keypress e.g. select multiple rows in an table by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd> or <kbd>shift</kbd>. To achieve that, we cache the key codes on `keydown` event and delete the keycodes on `keyup`:

```
var Global = {};
Global.Keys = {};

// cache pressing key on keydown
$(window).keydown(function (e) 
{
    Global.Keys[e.which] = true;
});

// delete pressing key on keyup
$(window).keyup(function (e) 
{
    delete Global.Keys[e.which];
});
```

Unfortunately, when pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>delete</kbd> in windows, the Task Manager appears and the last pressed key event <kbd>delete</kbd> does not reach the browser and gets lost.

**Problem:** When coming back to the browser, the codes of <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> keys are still cached and accidentally simulating key presses.

**Question:** How to delete all pressed and cached key codes from JavaScript when pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>delete</kbd>?

Comment: I don't think you can override a windows keyboard shortcut.

Comment: @evolutionxbox: My question is not "How can I override a windows keyboard shortcut?"

Comment: It kinda is. You want something to happen when you use an OS level shortcut. I think the OS event happens before the JS one would.

Comment: In times of web apps I should not be the only one who has this problem.

Comment: Have you checked the following? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2807838/capturing-ctrl-alt-del-in-javascript-jquery, http://robertwhurst.github.io/KeyboardJS/, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20711252/javascript-capturing-ctrlaltc

Comment: Yes, I have checked all of them → and now???

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125407/discussion-between-evolutionxbox-and-simon).